# Export variance-covariance matrix using PROC GLM

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, sas, covariance-matrix

I have a ordinary linear regression model like this

```
y = b0 + b1*x + b2*z + b3*x*z
```

I used `PROC GLM` in `SAS` to test the model. Now I want to export the variance-covariance matrix of the coefficients (`b0`, `b1`, `b2`, and `b3`). However, I didn't find any option to export it. I can't not use `PROC REG` because of the interaction term.

Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: By "can't not", do you mean simply that you *cannot* use `PROC REG`?

Answer (score 1):

If it is more convenient to export the variance-covariance matrix using `PROC REG`, then you can use that. You can get an interaction term by doing a `DATA` step first, and creating a new dataset with an extra variable that constitutes the `x` by `z` interaction.  The code might look something like this:

```
DATA new.data;
    SET data;
    xz = x*z;
RUN;
PROC REG DATA=new.data;
    MODEL y = x z xz /COVB;
RUN;
```